# Faster proportion tables in R

Tags: performance, r, xts

I am creating proportion tables based on an xts object. As this is part of a large program that (unfortunately) requires around 10^6 loops, it creates quite a bottleneck and I would like to speed it up.

This is an example of what I started with:

```
library(quantmod)

test.xts <- xts(sample(seq(1,5, by=.5), 50, replace=T), as.Date(1:50))

system.time(for(i in 1:10000){

  prop.table(table(test.xts))

})

>user  system elapsed 
 19.86    0.00   18.58
```

I have already changed the xts to a matrix and that resulted in a significant speed increase. I only mention that it is originally an xts in case I'm missing something with xts that would speed this up beyond the gains I've already seen converting it to a matrix.

```
test.mat <- as.matrix(test.xts)

system.time(for(i in 1:10000){

  prop.table(table(test.mat))

})

>user  system elapsed 
 2.78    0.00    2.90
```

But I'd really like it to be as fast as possible so I'm hoping that others out there have suggestions for further improvements. I'm hoping there's an obvious approach I'm overlooking.

One additional piece of information is that the output from these tables is ultimately merged with similar output from a different time period, so the dimensions need to remain named. (I.e., I need to be able to match the proportion for a value of '10' at time 1 with the proportion of '10' at time 2).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that actually creating the table is the bottleneck? That said, you could probably squeak out a bit more performance by using `tabulate` directly.

Comment: It's one of the major time sinks according to Rprof(). Obviously the looping is the major time issue, but unfortunately, completely vectorizing the code, which I'm not sure is even possible, is at least not feasible.

Comment: Sorry, I'm obviously new to posting so I didn't realize that hitting Return would submit the comment nor that I could only edit it for 5 mins, hence the double comment. Regarding the `tabulate` suggestion, I considered that but didn't see much potential benefit. I oversimplified a bit in the example, as the data are not integer (I'll update the question to reflect this). Dealing with that and adding named references to `tabulate` output would probably add overhead that negated any other speed gains. With that said, I didn't run any timings; I'll revisit it.

Comment: Major issue for `table` is to find unique values so the exact kind of data you have as values is important here. Your original question used integers which is the natural way to bin values, for anything else you either have to come up with a way that is native to your data use otherwise you'll have to go through strings (which is what `tables` does) and that is slow by definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`table()` implicitly creates a factor which is expensive. In your case you can save a lot (more than 10x) by using `tabulate()` since you already have integers:

```
a <- tabulate(test.mat)
names(a) <- seq_along(a)
a / sum(a)
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
0.16 0.14 0.08 0.14 0.08 0.16 0.02 0.06 0.10 0.06
```

timings:

```
system.time(for(i in 1:10000){
  a <- tabulate(test.mat)
  names(a) <- seq_along(a)
  a/sum(a)
})

 user  system elapsed 
0.208   0.002   0.210
```

your timing for comparison:

```
system.time(for(i in 1:10000) prop.table(table(test.mat)))
 user  system elapsed 
3.373   0.028   3.402
```

Comment: My apologies, I oversimplified the example. IRL the data have decimal values. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: So what do you want to do with that? round? take up to a certain digit? take exact value? Each of those has different solutions (see my comment above)

Comment: The end result doesn't matter, as long as it can be transformed back to the original values. In other words, if converting the original values (which have one decimal place and move in increments of .5) to integers by multiplying by 10 allows a faster process, that's okay. I can convert the values back to the original scale outside of the loop. With this in mind, I tried using your code with the input multiplied by 10 (e.g., `test.mat*10`), but it slowed things considerably. I imagine this has something to do with the fact that `tabulate` evaluates all integers in the range.

Answer (score 3):

TO build on joran's comment, using `tabulate()` directly can prove faster. It does have three quirks worth noting:

1. It only deals with integers and truncates decimals.
2. It silently ignores all negative values and zeros.
3. It creates a bin for all values 1:n, even if there are zero counts

See `?tabulate` for details.

With that caveat, here's a function that gives ~9x speed up:

```
prop2 <- function(x){
  x <- tabulate(x)
  out <- x/sum(x)
  names(out) <- seq_along(out)
  return(out)
}
```

Test speed:

```
library(rbenchmark)
test.mat <- as.matrix(test.xts)
f1 <- function() prop.table(table(test.mat))
benchmark(f1(), prop2(test.mat),
           replications = 1000,
           columns = c("test", "relative", "elapsed"),
           order = "relative")
#------
             test relative elapsed
2 prop2(test.mat)      1.0    0.10
1            f1()      9.1    0.91
```

Confirm output is same:

```
> prop.table(table(test.mat))
test.mat
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
0.04 0.02 0.20 0.12 0.08 0.10 0.06 0.14 0.12 0.12 
> prop2(test.mat)
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
0.04 0.02 0.20 0.12 0.08 0.10 0.06 0.14 0.12 0.12
```

Comment: FWIW *never* use `1:length(x)` because it doesn't do what you think it does for 0-length `x` and it is a major source of bugs in R code. It is inefficient as well, so you're better off with `seq_along`

Comment: *"It silently ignores all negative values and zeros."* See the quirky code around `table()` line 99 which maps every value other than a positive integer to a positive integer (and squelches non-contiguous gaps): `bin <- bin + 1L * (a - 1L)`